# HTML : Invalid input number in Internet Explorer/ Edge Form

Tags: html, forms

When I put some specific numbers in the HTML input text-box, I can't submit it with the last version of Internet Explorer or Edge. It says "Invalid Number".  For exemple, "43.7" is considered as an invalid number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
        <p>
        <label for="value"></label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="value" id="value" min="35" /> 
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : The problem is apparently related to the "min" value.
No problem appears if we put "30" as min value.

Thank you for your help.

Quentin

Comment: Is the snippet supposed to work? It does nothing on any browser. In any case, if your regional settings use comma as decimal separator the number *may* indeed be invalid. Browsers appear to be extremely incoherent with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround:

```js
$("input[type='button'").click(function(){
  console.log("Submitted value " + $("input[type='number'").val());
  $("input[type='number'").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
        <p>
        <label for="value"></label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" name="value" id="value" min="35" /> 
        </p>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not the Culture fault.  It's not working at all with a comma, "Not a Number", but it's working with "43.75" for exemple.

Comment: Do you have a workaround that can be implemented in the html (without js)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" name="value" id="value" min="35" />
```

or a regular expression to set the pattern attribute

```
<input type="number" pattern="^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$" name="value" id="value" min="35" />
```